# How to prevent error message when importing import cv2?

Tags: python, opencv, jupyter-notebook, pip, jupyter-lab

what does this error mean? I have opencv installed using pip install opencv-python. I’m using Python 3 and am in Jupyter Notebook.

```
import cv2
```

> TypeError: 'numpy._DTypeMeta' object is not subscriptable

I tried importing opencv but it produced an error message

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: My guess is you have incompatible versions of opencv and numpy.

Comment: Note that "I have opencv installed using pip install opencv-python" is missing _three_ version numbers there. Which version of Python, and which version of pip, which version of opencv?

Comment: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/23822

Answer (score 5):

I encountered this issue when I was using `numpy 1.21.5` along with
`cv2 4.8.0` in `Python 3.9.13`.

Upgrading to `numpy 1.25.2` resolved the issue for me.

`pip install --upgrade numpy`

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. Unfortunately, the same error message still appeared. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Change your numpy version

```
pip install opencv-python==4.8.0.74
```

Comment: Doing this after upgrading numpy left me we with the following message 

ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
tables 3.8.0 requires blosc2~=2.0.0, but you have blosc2 2.2.6 which is incompatible.
numba 0.57.0 requires numpy<1.25,>=1.21, but you have numpy 1.26.2 which is incompatible. 

how should i address this.

Comment: This command does not change the numpy version.